# Populate a text field from autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to populate a field ("Number") when a value is selected in autocomplete field ("Name"). Please see this **UPDATED** [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/PatrickObrian/5U4DR/4/)

Let's say I have a two sets of data. Set 1 contain names and set 2 - numbers. They are related, like: 
  NAME A = 0001

NAME B = 0002

NAME C = 0003 etc

```
<div>
<table>
    <div id="Q101" class="printable">
        <tr>
            <td width="41" align="left" valign="top">
                <div class="QNumber">1.1</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="baseline">
                <div class="QText">Name:</div>
            </td>
            <td width="300">
                <div class="Response">
                    <input name="Text" type="text" id="vslName" size="31">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>

        <div id="Q102">
        <tr>
            <td width="41" align="left" valign="top">
                <div class="QNumber">1.2</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="baseline">
                <div class="QText">Number:</div>
            </td>
            <td width="300">
                <div class="Response">
                    <input name="Text" type="text" id="Q101" size="10">
                </div>
            </td>
            < </tr>
    </div>
</table>
</div>
```

What I would like to have is when user selects NAME from autocomplete field (id="vslName"), number is automatically populated into filed IMO NUMBER (id="Q101"). Another question - where to place NUMBERS? I keep autocomplete values right in the function, since there going to be maximum 50sh entries. Thus:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "AZOV SEA",
      "BARENTS SEA",
      "KARA SEA",
      "EAST SIBERIAN SEA",
      "TUCHKOV BRIDGE",
    ];
    $( "#vslName" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

Thank you in advance!
PS. I am not a pro in JS and therefore "pardon my French" if this is a trifle task for you guys))))) 
PS.2 - In the code above type="text" could be "number" - does not really matter atm)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use [jQuery UI's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

EDIT: If you are using jQuery UI's autocomplete, then you need to bind to the `select` event to handle that. See http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select for details.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$("#vslName").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var tag = ui.item.value;
        $('input#Q101').val(availableTags.indexOf(tag) + 1);
    }
});
```

I'm not 100% sure about whether this will work, but the basic idea is that on the select event, you get the value of the selected tag, then set the value of the input to the text contained in that tag.

EDIT: As I mentioned in my comment, JavaScript lacks a construct like hashes or dictionaries, which are the obvious way to accomplish this, but it can be faked.

First of all, your array needs to be an array of objects, not just an array of strings. You need to define the `label` and `value` properties for jQuery UI. You can also define your own properties, so if you create a `number` property as well, that should do the job.

Something like this would be suitable:

```
var availableTags = Array;
availableTags[0] = { "name": "AZOV SEA", "value": "AZOV SEA", "number": 0 };
```

Repeat the `availableTags` line for each remaining  tag, incrementing the number each time. Then, you can use the `$.grep` method to fetch the number property for the selected tag, like this:

```
var tag = ui.item.value;
var item = $.grep(availableTags, function (e) { return e.name == tag; });
$('input#Q101').val(item[0].number);
```

Comment: It is used! For the field auto complete which is NAME))))) The function above IS jQuery autocomplete)))

Comment: The question is to pass value into field NUMBER!

Comment: @Alexander The JSFiddle you linked to doesn't appear to include jQuery UI

Comment: @Matthew, Yeh, but where would you keep NUMBERS?

Comment: @Alexander In most other programming languages, that's what a dictionary, hash or associative array is for. JavaScript doesn't actually have that, however you can fake it using jQuery's grep method. I shall update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Matthew, thank you, will try! USing this .grep method, do I have to alter autocomplete function?

Comment: @Alexander Yes. What you need to be able to do using $.grep is to find the item with a given name and retrieve it, so that you can then retrieve its number. That belongs in the callback for the select method.

Comment: may I ask you for an example? I am afraid I am not that much of JS guy yet))))

Comment: @Alexander Glad to hear it. I get the impression you're struggling somewhat with jQuery - if that's the case, I suggest you check out the excellent video tutorials at https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Basically you're right - I am new to all these and building an offline form is a learning task for me)))) Thanks for the reference!))